# Does extra-, intra-polation fall under abduction, induction or deduction?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Philosophy Stack Exchange post: [Does extra-, intra-polation fall under abduction, induction or deduction?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/86467/does-extra-intra-polation-fall-under-abduction-induction-or-deduction)

Why was this closed? How can I edit it to reopen it?